# Vue js Load xmlns schema after updating DOM

Tags: vue.js, dom, mathml

I am dynamically updating the dom with vue js, but i discovered that my math tag is not being loaded after vue updates the dom.
for example, this code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<p>
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msqrt>
      <mi>x</mi>
      <mi>y</mi>
    </msqrt>
  </math>
</p>
```

is supposed to display the square root of xy.
If i copy this code and paste it in a clean html file, it works well, but if it is rendered by vue, the math tag gets rendered as normal text.
Is there a way to force vue to load the xmlns schema of the math object before updating the dom with it?

Comment: You probably need to ignore the math tag for it to work: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852556/how-to-display-mathml-correctly-with-vue

Comment: The math tag is added dynamically, i use ckeditor wiris plugin to create them

Comment: Can you show exactly how you're getting the tag to be _"rendered by vue_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later discovered that this was a compatibility issue with browsers.
Some browsers do not render math tags

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you're using something like

```html
<p>{{ mathTag }}</p>
```

when what you should be using is [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)...

```html
<p v-html="mathTag"></p>
```

or even better, assuming it's the specific MathML tags you want to render dynamically, `<component>`

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    operation: 'msqrt',
    identifiers: ['x', 'y']
  })
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <math>
    <component :is="operation">
      <mi v-for="(identifier, i) in identifiers" :key="i">{{ identifier }}</mi>
    </component>
  </math>
</div>
```